# Backbone.js remove surrounding div from template

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Im my popover module the template is loaded view ajax.

```
function(app) {

  var Popover = app.module();

  Popover.Views.Default = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: "popover/template",

    initialize: function(options) {
      this.reference = options.reference;
      this.render();
    },

    beforeRender: function() {
      this.content = this.$el.find('.popover');
    }
  });

  // Required, return the module for AMD compliance.
  return Popover;
});
```

Renders:

```
<div>
    <div class="popover">content</div>
</div>
```

While the template just includes

```
<div class="popover">content</div>
```

**How can I remove the sorrounding div?**

Comment: How is your `template`? Is it include the `div`?

Comment: No the div is not included in the template, see my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to override the `render` function as:

```
 render:function () {
     this.$el.html(_.template(this.template));
     return this;
 }
```

In case you are using `underscore` to load templates...

---

If you want only the `div` you can add the `className` to the View:

```
Popover.Views.Default = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: "popover/template",

    className: 'popover',

    initialize: function(options) {
      this.reference = options.reference;
      this.render();
    },

    beforeRender: function() {
      this.content = this.$el.find('.popover');
    }
  });
```

Then the template only has the content, not the `div`.

Comment: still same problem, prints <div>popover/template</div>

Comment: First, you have to load the template, are you using `underscore`?

Comment: Yes I use underscore, however your suggestion still prints the template path instead the template

Comment: @artworkadシ Oh that is because you are not using `text` plugin for `require` to load the template... Anyway Backbone is wrapping the content with a `div`...